# Set text in TextView using Html.fromHtml get fail

Tags: android, textview, fromhtml

I have an string as `Test 1 < 2 (1<2) <br /><br /><br />Best Regards,` and I want to display it on a `TextView`, expected result must be

```
Test 1 < 2 (1<2) 

Best Regards,
```

I had used `text.setText(Html.fromHtml(mString));` to archive but my output is

```
Test 1 < 2 (1

Best Regards,
```

Any one can help me for solving this problem ?

**Note that the value of string is fixed, can not change its content.**

Comment: don't use `Html#fromHtml`, better use `Spannable#setSpan` method

Comment: how to call setSpan? Spannable is an interface

Comment: @CreativeAndroid I can not change the content of the string, it's data from Server